# Date from MySQL database not displaying in Angular view

Tags: mysql, angularjs, typescript

So I'm using Angularjs with TypeScript to make a simple to-do list as a webpage just for fun/practice.  This is my controller which queries the database and stores the objects:

```
module app.ToDo {

    class ToDoCtrl {
        toDoItems: app.domain.ToDoItems[];

        static $inject = ["dataAccessService"];
        constructor(private dataAccessService: app.common.DataAccessService)
        {
            this.toDoItems = [];

            var toDoResource = dataAccessService.getToDoResource();
            toDoResource.query((data: app.domain.ToDoItems[]) => {
                this.toDoItems = data;
            });
        }
    }

    angular.module("toDoManagement").controller("ToDoCtrl", ToDoCtrl);
}
```

Here is my ToDoItems class:

```
module app.domain {
    export class ToDoItems {
        constructor(public id: number, public title: string, public description: string,
        public due: Date, public completed: boolean) { }
    }
}
```

Those are all of the fields in my database.  This is my view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Due Date</td>
            <td>Completed</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in vm.toDoItems">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.due}}</td>
            <td>{{item.completed}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is the `Due` column shows up empty for each row.  Is this some sort of formatting error from MySQL to JavaScript?  The `Due` field in my database is of type `DATE` not `DATETIME` in case that's relevant.

**FIXED:** The problem was the variable that because of the way I named the variable in the database, the value for `Due` was being assigned to a variable that didn't exist in the class and was instead making its own variable named `due_Date` that I didn't know about.  I just had to change the binding from `{{item.due}}` to `{{item.due_Date}}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark but does the date filter in angular help?

{{ item.todo | date : 'medium' }}

I think that's it just off the top of my head

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Sorry it was such a silly error.

Comment: Yeah {{ items | json }} is a life saver =)